# How to make host send a DNS-request without waiting for a response?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

```
How to make host send a DNS-request without waiting for a response?
```

I want to use host (in a loop) to send out a series of DNS-requests without waiting for corresponding responses.

```
host foo.com 192.168.16.2 -W 1
```

waits for 1 second before exiting. If I set `-W 0`, then it automatically gets set to 1. That is, each iteration of my loop takes at least 1 second, which I want to avoid.

Comment: "each iteration of my loop takes at least 1 second" -- if `host` timeouts; normally it may return sooner. Do you need the responses? or maybe you just want to DOS-attack the server?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I don't need the responses. I'm just trying to implement a simple DNS exfiltration of data, i.e., send data over DNS.

Comment: You can run `host` in background and immediately loop; or use `timeout` with a fraction of a second, yet still long enough for `host` to send a request. These are workarounds. I think `host` will always try to wait, unless you modify its source and build your own. Note the primary job of `host` is *obtaining* a response; requests are just necessary means to do this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - thank you for your suggestions, I will try them out. Up for a bonus question? Do you know how to make `host` send just one DNS-request instead of two (default)? I know it sends two requests for fault-tolerance, but in this case I just want one.

Comment: No, I don't know. Maybe you should drop `host` and seek (write?) a tool that suits your needs better?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *care* about the responses, then don't use DNS lookup tools, because they were specifically made to wait for the response and show it.

There are dedicated traffic generation tools. Scapy is popular and has functions to craft DNS packets (among many other things).

The protocol itself is anyway stateless and simple enough that you could also capture and replay the raw UDP packets containing live queries, only changing the query ID if needed. For example, once you have a file containing a DNS query, `nc` or `socat` can send it.

Comment: Thank you! What option do you use with netcat to replay?